# How to serialize TreeView and DataGridView along with strings

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I have a windows form application in C#. I need to save the form data to an xml file. I can save all the text in textboxes as given in this tutorial using strings [C# Tutorial - XML Serialization](http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization)

I am unable to figure out how to Serialize TreeView and DataGridView to the same xml file. Tried the solution given here[How to serialize treeview in to xml and deserialize xml back to treeview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892114/how-to-serialize-treeview-in-to-xml-and-deserialize-xml-back-to-treeview)
but unable to save the data to a single xml file. While deserializing, the strings are populated in the treeview instead of the nodes.

Comment: The UI is not serializable. You should serialize *data*, not the UI. The UI and the *data* should be separated  properly to allow this. You will always struggle until you create a  proper separation.

Comment: If you want a single XML file you need to wrap all your objects into a single class and then serialize the class.  An XML file can have only one root node so you can't simply combine three objects that are serialize individually.

Comment: @jdweng I tried creating a Class and then saving the values in the object of the class and save that to an XML. The strings in the textboxes work, however TreeViews and DataGridViews throw an exception of an error reflecting type.